# Second bankruptcy hearing

Tags: bankruptcy

Say you have had a hearing and it was thrown out for lack of evidence.
Now you're having a second hearing with a new judge.  Does he have to read all the new evidence, or can he throw it out, too?

Comment: I don't understand the question: Are you asking whether a judge can enter an order without considering the evidence presented to the court?  Or something more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail, it's hard to know what you mean.  Under reasonable circumstances judges do want to understand new evidence at hearings.  However they have wide latitude.

A judge doesn't, technically, have to read everything you submit.  For example, in *Chevron Corp. v. The Weinberg Group* (D.D.C. 2012) Judge Facciola stated, "Here, I would have to review 9,171 pages of documents. That seems inconceivable given my advanced years"  (the background was a requested privilege review).

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Answer (score 1):

Judges are pragmatic creatures.  I am of the opinion that one in ten pages of motions and other documents I have proffered to judges in the last 5 years have been read in their entirety.  The other 9-in-10 have been skimmed at best, ignored at worst.